# Accessing Structs within Structs in C

Tags: c, list, struct, tree, linked-list

Just a very brief question really which stemmed from another post, if I were to access my char *number within my ListNode, from my TreeNode, so that each TreeNode each has its own linked list of numbers, would I access it as follows ( where TreeNode *root):

```
root->name = strdup(name); root->numbers->number = strdup(number);
```

Cheers!

```
typedef struct ListNode {
  char            *number;
  struct ListNode *next;
}ListNode;

typedef struct TreeNode {
  char            *name;
  ListNode        *numbers;
  struct TreeNode *left;
  struct TreeNode *right;
}TreeNode;
```

EDIT: Here is my function to add a TreeNode and List to that Node:

```
int main(void) {
char my_string[50], name[25], number[25];
TreeNode *root = NULL;
ListNode *list = NULL;
while ((fgets(my_string, 50, stdin)) != NULL) {
    if (my_string[0] == '.')
        break;      
sscanf(my_string, "%s %s", name, number); 
root = AddNode(root, list, name, number);
}   
return 0;
}

TreeNode* AddNode(TreeNode *root, ListNode *list, char *name, char *number) {
int comparison;
if ( root == NULL) {
    root = (TreeNode *)malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
    list = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    root->name = strdup(name); root->numbers->number = strdup(number);
    root->left = root->right = NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're passing in a pointer to a `ListNode`, but then are mallocing a `ListNode`, assigning to it, and not doing anything with it. I'm not sure what your intent is there:

```
list = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
```

The reason for the segfault is that you malloc a `TreeNode` but not the `ListNode` inside of it. You need to do:

```
root = (TreeNode *)malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
root->numbers = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
```

Or if that's what you meant to do with the `ListNode` you malloc'd, you need to assign it:

```
root = (TreeNode *)malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
list = (ListNode *)malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
root->numbers = list;
```

Comment: Similarly then, to how I set root->left and root->right to NULL, at the end of my code, would I also do the same with root->numbers->next, so that the next pointer of my list, for that TreeNode, points to NULL?

Comment: One thing you can do is use `calloc()` instead of `malloc()`. `calloc()` allocates the memory then zero-fills it, therefore any pointers you haven't assigned to will be `NULL` **Edit:** To clarify - Yes, you want `root->numbers->next` to be `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't forget to malloc() that ListNode in there, that's the way to go!

Comment: But I seem to seg fault when I access in that way, any ideas? I am mallocing it, since atm I am only testing with root == NULL to begin with.

Comment: you should add that piece of info in the question.

Comment: Checking root as NULL? So when you start off building the tree, the call is AddNode(NULL, ....)  - is that so?

Comment: In your AddNode, you should have a line like `root->numbers = list`

Comment: You're mallocating list, a local pointer and NOT the one inside root.

Answer (score 0):

i think `root->numbers->number` is causing the segment violation, you do not seem to set `root->numbers` to point to anything before you de-reference it.